# Why does Big Sur change my custom Mail keyboard shortcuts, and how do I make it stop?

Tags: mail.app, shortcut, big-sur

One of the keyboard shortcuts that annoys me the most is Cmd + Shift + D to send an e-mail in Mail. Clunky, illogical, ergonomically awkward, hard to remember – there’s just absolutely nothing good about it. I use, and have always used, Cmd + Enter instead.

I do this by adding a custom App Shortcut in System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts:

[image: Custom shortcut for ‘Send’]

This has worked fine for as long as I can remember, and still works fine on my desktop computer running Catalina (10.15.7). On my new M1 MacBook Pro running Big Sur, however, it doesn’t work so fine.

I can still add the shortcut, and Mail also picks it up, but in the Message menu, my Cmd + Enter has suddenly and auto-not-so-magically become Cmd + Shift + Enter. Not what I asked for. Better than Cmd + Shift + D, but still an unnecessary third keystroke and a lot more awkward than what I actually specified.

Why does this happen? Are we no longer allowed to add custom App Shortcuts with only one modifier key? Is it a bug? Does Cmd + Enter conflict with something else that it didn’t use to conflict with before? And more importantly, **can I fix it**?